# How to use a radioButton in Xaml for XAmarin.Forms?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to use the radio button in Xamarin.Forms application.
Is it possible to use the RadioButton in Xamarin.Forms application?

Please check the below image for the design and requirements.

[image]

Comment: I have used a list view with the radio button images and on tapping any of the item, I coded in view model to display selected radio button image and other items images to be non selected radio button image. Also I store the selected item for the further process. This way you can make any radio button designs based on the UI design.

Answer (score 0):

To implement Radio Button in Xamarin.Forms (Portable) you can use the below NuGet packages.

- https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs (Suggested)
- https://github.com/kirtisagar/XamarinFormsRadioButtonXAML

Example: https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/tree/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/RadioButton

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a Xamarin.Forms picker:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/picker/populating-itemssource#populating-a-picker-with-data

```XAML
<Picker x:Name="UtilityPicker" Title="Select a utility">
    <Picker.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>All</x:String>
            <x:String>Time Check</x:String>
            <x:String>Traffic Update</x:String>
            <x:String>PPF</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Picker.ItemsSource>
</Picker>
```

[image]
[image]